# Custom Qt controls in C++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use a custom control in Qt, but don't know how.

My current main code:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;
    window.setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
    window.show();
    return application.exec();
}
```

`MainWindow` ui has a `QTextEdit` and a `PushButton`. Now, I want to use another control that inherits from `QTextEdit`.

I've added a [`CodeEditor`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-codeeditor-example.html) class that is taken from the documentation, but it doesn't appear in Qt Creator designer.

Comment: So to be clear, you want to use the Designer to add your custom QWidget to the ui? The feature you are looking for is "promote" in the Designer.

Comment: @hyde Exactly what I was looking for! You can post if as an answer :)

Comment: I'd have to make a test project to see how exactly it was done in Designer again, and don't want to write a one-line answer. So go ahead and answer yourself of you want. Or find a duplicate and link to it (there probably is one).